# pydub audiosegement gives a FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, audiosegment

I'm trying to work with pydub to get the times of each word spoken in an audio file, but python throws me a FileNotFoundError

**The code:**

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.silence import detect_nonsilent

path = "E:/PyApps/New/PythonApplication1/OSR_us_000_0010_8k.wav"
audio_segment = AudioSegment.from_wav(path)
```

**The error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "E:\PyApps\New\PythonApplication1\module1.py", line 5, in 
> audio_segment = AudioSegment.from_wav(path)
> File "C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 808, in from_wav
> return cls.from_file(file, 'wav', parameters=parameters)
> File "C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 728, in from_file
> info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)
> File "C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 274, in mediainfo_json
> res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
> File "C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in **init**
> self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
> File "C:\Users\Dean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
> hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

whats weird is that I've got all the files specified in the error in the right folder but it still can't find them for some reason.